# After Installing Push Notifications with Firebase in an Ionic + Angular plugin can't create build and run in android

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic5

After installing firebase push notification plugin in ionic angular can not create build and run in android.

I am install below plugin:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated
$ npm install @ionic-native/fcm
```

And I got below error:

> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices
> Parsing json file: C:\MyApp_new\platforms\android\app\google-services.json

```
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
C:\MyApp_new\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\ionicframework\cordova\webview\IonicWebViewEngine.java:11: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
                                 ^
C:\MyApp_new\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\ionicframework\cordova\webview\IonicWebViewEngine.java:137: error: cannot find symbol
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
     ^
  symbol:   class RequiresApi
  location: class IonicWebViewEngine.ServerClient
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Comment: May I recommend you to use **[this Cordova plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex)** for push notifications with Firebase? The owner of that plugin does a great job keeping it up-to-date and I'm using it in quite a few production apps.

Comment: @sebaferreras i use this plugin but can't get token id